# Delete project based on sample, then sample no longer available?

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a new project based on the Wikitionary sample.

After tinkering with it so much and screwing it up, I decided to delete the project and start over again.

After deleting my project, I find that the Wiktionary sample is no longer available as a starting point.

Are these one-and-done samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a one-and-done sample, you simply deleted it so you just have to download it again.

Just clear up all the folders that you have right now, download the source code again, and create new project in Eclipse from the existing source code. You should be OK then.

Comment: So, when I create a project based on the sample I am actually editing the sample itself?

I thought it would make a copy for me and keep the sample there.

OK, I cna live with that but it wasn't the behavior I was expecting.

I should create a project for the sample then somehow immediately copy it to another working project so I can edit without worrying about messing up the sample.

Thanks